# ¿Cómo puedo cambiar la ruta por defecto de una base de datos en Android?

Tags: android, android-studio, sqlite, android-sqlite

He creado una base de datos SQLite y necesito poder utilizarla en mi aplicación de Android. La ruta por defecto es /data/data/mi_aplicacion/databases/Mi_DB.db pero sin ser root no tengo acceso. ¿Existe el modo de cambiar dicha ruta para poder colocar la base de datos en la micro sd y trabajar desde allí?

El código que actualmente estoy usando como ejemplo es este:

```
public AdminSQLiteOpenHelper(Context context, String name,SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version)
 {
    super(context, name, factory, version);
}

@Override

public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("create table Mi_tabla(Campo1 int primary key,Campo2 int,Campo3 text,Campo4 text)");
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

}
```

Muchas gracias de antemano!

Answer (score -1):

Tendras que hacerlo en el nombre de la BD yo lo hago de la siguiente forma.

```
public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "ejemplo.db";
public DataBaseHelper(Context context, String PATH) {
    super(context, PATH+"/"+DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);}
```

Cuando quiero realizar una conexión a la BD

```
PATH="/data/data/mi_aplicacion/databases/"
DataBaseHelper dataBaseHelper = new DataBaseHelper(getApplicationContext(),
                Constructores.path);
```

El Path es la ruta donde la quieras almacenar debe ser una ruta valida para que no te de ningun error al momento de consultar nuevamente los registros que almacenes o desee almacenar.

Para encontrar la ruta de la tarjeta SD existen varios métodos que te pueden ayudar pero con Android hay un problemita y es que esa ruta de la tarjeta depende del fabricante y la versión de android siempre no estará en la misma ubicación. Por ejemplo yo uso este código para encontrar mi ruta.

```
/**
 * metodo para listar los directorios de los almacenamientos externos
 *
 * @param pContext Contexto
 * @return Lista String con las rutas.
 */
public static String getStorageDirectories(Context pContext) {
    //Get primary & secondary external device storage (internal storage & micro SDCARD slot...)
    File[] listExternalDirs = ContextCompat.getExternalFilesDirs(pContext, null);
    File extStore = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    for (int i = 0; i < listExternalDirs.length; i++) {

        if (listExternalDirs[i] != null) {
            String path = listExternalDirs[i].getAbsolutePath();
            if (path.contains("-")) {
                return path;
            } else {
                if (path.contains("extsdcard")) {
                    return path;
                } else {
                    if (path.contains("extSdCard")) {
                        return path;
                    } else {
                        if (path.contains("sdcard")) {
                            return path;
                        } else {
                            if (path.contains("external_sd")) {
                                return path;
                            } else {
                                if (path.contains("external_SD")) {
                                    return path;
                                } else {
                                    if (path.contains("ext_sd")) {
                                        return path;
                                    } else {
                                        if (path.contains("sdext")) {
                                            return path;
                                        } else {
                                            if (path.contains("sdcard1")) {
                                                return path;
                                            }else {
                                                if(new File("/storage/sdcard1/").exists())
                                                {
                                                    path=path.replace(extStore.toString() ,"/storage/sdcard1");
                                                    return path;
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        }

    }

    return "";
}
```

Comment: De esta forma se cambia el path, pero estando en data/data no es almacenamiento externo, el OP quiere guardarla dentro de su micro SD.

Comment: Pues da igual hay métodos para encontrar la ruta de la tarjeta SD luego de que tenga esa ruta cambias ese path y listo. He modificado la respuesta con un método que he utilizado en un proyecto personal